minicom: невозможно открыть /dev/modem: нет такого файла или каталога
Работаю с minicom, при вводе команды minicom -c on -b 115200 /dev/ttyUSB0 выдает ошибку из названия вопроса. Перенастройка serial port'а через minicom -s не помогает, minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB0 переводит в другое подменю без возможности настройки порта(насколько я понял). Пожалуйста, помогите, очень нужно.
